# Is it a good practice to update redux state for the TextInput for every onChangeText

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

Am a newbie in React Native and redux too. But somehow managed to start doing the applications. So my question is that should i need to update the state of redux for every change of text for any text input component.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a local state in your class component. So whenever you are changing the text you can affect this local state.
After submitting your text, you can store it in the redux state.